# How to get the most recent data received through Bluetooth which is stored in a folder

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth

I am currently developing an android application on eclipse using the android 2.3.3 platform.

This application takes in an RFID tag's ID from external hardware that my partner is building.

After the android application receives the ID, it processes it further.

- I will need to keep checking for the RFID tag's ID as it can be sent
  anytime.
- I know that All the data that I receive through bluetooth
  will be stored in a folder and I need to access it.

But my question is: Is it possible to keep checking in a folder for the most recent data I received?

Answer (score 4):

By using the following code you can do it

```
    final String pathToWatch1 =     
    android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/bluetooth";       

    observer1 = new FileObserver(pathToWatch1) 
    { 
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String file) 
        {
        if(event == FileObserver.CREATE && !file.equals(".probe")){
                Log.v("tag", "blue tooth [" + android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/bluetooth" + file + "]");

            } 

        }
    };
    observer1.startWatching();
```

Comment: Never heard this method before. Good job